# How do I display an integer column of a given table as an auto-incrementing series starting from 1 to a front-end user?

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server

I'm in the midst of writing a full-stack application that acts as a task/project manager. It acts as a big table with a drag and drop feature that allows upper-management to re-prioritize tasks/projects. Here is what upper-management sees.

```
 -----------------------------------------
|Priority| Task                 | Resource|
 -----------------------------------------
|    1   | Write some code      | Arya S. |
 -----------------------------------------
|    2   | Write a spec.        | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
|    3   | Write some code      | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
```

... and so forth for 100+ tasks.
The resource for whom the task is assigned can also sign into the program and only see their tasks. For example, if Bran logs in:

```
 -----------------------------------------
|Priority| Task                 | Resource|
 -----------------------------------------
|    2   | Write a spec.        | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
|    3   | Write some code      | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
```

The priority column is a column in our sql-server database. **Is there a way to use SQL to re-adjust the priority (either through the middle-tier JAVA code, or through a SQL view) so that 'Bran S.' sees his priorities starting from 1?** Desired end-product:

```
 -----------------------------------------
|Priority| Task                 | Resource|
 -----------------------------------------
|    1   | Write a spec.        | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
|    2   | Write some code      | Bran S. |
 -----------------------------------------
```

I would prefer not to have to use JQuery/DOM manipulation as it seems inefficient and messy and there are a lot of moving parts. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for a framework like reactjs

Comment: As for the second part, your backend show only expose to the front end the tasks that the user can see. For example, if user "A" asks the backend for a list of tasks, the backend should only return a list of tasks for that user, nothing more. In your backend you would have to filter

Comment: Not looking for a framework for this specific problem. Everything I have shown here is currently a working application. A resource can login to the program and only see his/her tasks, but the priorities don't re-adjust to start from 1. This is a small detail in my opinion (as it's easy to infer what you need to prioritize most since the table is sorted by priority), but it needs to be part of the finished product.

Comment: I see, you want the priority remapping in the backend rather than the frontend?

Comment: Yep!! Precisely

Comment: Just count on the client side. Hiding the actual IDs is a recipe for headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, Row_Number() may be useful here.

**Example**

```
 Select [Priority] = row_number() over (partition by [resouce] order by [Priority])
       ,[Task]
       ,[Resouce]
  From  YourTable
```

**Note:** If you have competing priorities, you can replace `row_number()` with `dense_rank()`

To update your table...

```
;with cte as (
 Select *
       ,[NewPriority] = row_number() over (partition by [resouce] order by [Priority])
  From  YourTable
)
Update cte set [Priority]=[NewPriority]
```

Comment: @R.Verner Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number() frunction in the procedure or the select command you are using.

script

```
        create table #tempTable
        (
        Priority int identity(1,1),
            Task    varchar(100),
            Resource varchar(100)
            )

        insert into  #tempTable
        select    'Write some code' ,'Arya S.' UNION 
        select  'Write a spec. '  ,'Bran S.' union 
        select 'Write some code ' ,'Bran S.'

        select * from #tempTable

        select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Priority),Task,  Resource
        from    #tempTable

        delete from #tempTable
        where Priority = 1

        select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Priority) Priority,Task,    Resource
        from    #tempTable

        drop table #tempTable
```